# How to access mobile-friendly HTML-only Gmail site in Kindle browser

Tags: gmail, mobile, kindle

I can access a very plain, bare-bones but functional interface for Gmail using my ancient Windows mobile phone. When I navigate to `mail.google.com` on it, I'm redirected to `mail.google.com/mail/x/<stuff>`.

I would like to be able to access *this* version of Gmail from my Kindle 3, but I can't figure out how. Browsing directly to `mail.google.com/mail/x` redirects me to `mail/mu/`, which is the fancy mobile version for iPhones, etc. (presumably because the Kindle browser is a WebKit). That version is not very usable because of the Kindle's slow refresh rate (and besides I usually keep JavaScript off on the Kindle browser).

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For the HTML version that you can bookmark:

https://mail.google.com/?ui=html

Answer (score 0):

The link to the mobile-friendly Gmail is accessible by this shortcut:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/

It is not the same as what you get when you go to m.gmail.com on your computer, but it is faster and it fits the screen.  You can also go to m.gmail.com and select older version on the bottom.

Tips: Click Inbox (number of unread) to refresh

You need JavaScript for this one.

You can not click the menu options, you have to go to the /mail/h version.

This one really works.

Comment: That's not mobile-friendly, that's HTML-only.