# Will mobile-friendly URLs still work in desktop browsers when Gmail retires their Basic HTML view in 2024?

Tags: gmail

I use the following "Mobile Gmail" links in Chrome browser on my laptop:

- [mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/)
- [m.gmail.com](https://m.gmail.com)
- [mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/](https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/.)

Google has announced that users can only use the "Basic HTML" view in a browser until January 2024, and after that they'll automatically be switched to the "Standard" view: 
[Gmail Help > Use the latest version of Gmail in your browser](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049).

I'm trying to understand if this change affects the mobile-friendly links I'm using.

I got the links originally  from this [2012 answer on Web Apps by @Anonymus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26561/).

There was some disagreement as to whether the links are "Mobile Gmail" or "HTML Gmail" so I am not sure whether they are affected by the January 2024 change.

For example,

- Will the links still work?
- Will my Gmail experience, and/or the links I need to use, change?

Comment: Related [How to set Gmail "Basic HTML" as Default/Standard (for slow connections)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/151823/88163)

Answer (score 2):

Based solely on [Google's announcement](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049), after January 2024, the **Basic HTML** view will no longer be available and Google will redirect users to the default view of [gmail.com](https://gmail.com) that matches their platform and browser settings (see table below).

I haven't found information indicating what Google's intentions are for the **Older Version** of the **Mobile** view, however,  as helpfully pointed out by @user1686, it is a distinct view from **Basic HTML**, so presumably it is safe for now and continuing to use that (or switching to it) may be a good option for you.
[image: Comment by @user1686 noting that Basic HTML GMail and the Older Version of Mobile Gmail are not the same]

The **Older Version** of the **Mobile** view is significantly more limited (or "lighter" depending on your perspective) than the **Basic HTML** view they are retiring.

Keeping it may reflect the reality that, at this time, there remains a need for a feature-limited view of Gmail, and its simplicity fits the bill far better than the **Basic HTML** version which is loaded with features, and actually far from "basic."

## Gmail Views

There are currently four browser-based views for Gmail.  Two are intended for mobile browsers and two are intended for desktop browsers.

1. **Standard** Desktop
2. **Basic HTML** Desktop *(Unavailable after Jan. 2024)*
3. **Mobile**
4. **Older Version** Mobile

Google resolves the same link to completely different Gmail views depending on a user's platform and browser settings.

For example, the table below lists which Gmail **view** a particular link will resolve to based on the user's platform (desktop vs. mobile) and the browser mode (desktop vs. mobile):

| URL | Mobile Browser | Desktop Mode <sup>*****</sup> <sub>*Mobile Browser*</sub> | Desktop Browser | Mobile Mode<sup>*****</sup> <sub>*Desktop Browser*</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [gmail.com](https://gmail.com) | Mobile | Mobile | Standard | Mobile |
| [m.gmail.com](https://m.gmail.com) | Mobile | Mobile | Older Version (Mobile) | Mobile |
| [mail.google.com/mail/x/](https://mail.google.com/mail/x/) | Mobile | Older Version (Mobile) | Older Version (Mobile) | Mobile |
| [mail.google.com/mail/h/](https://mail.google.com/mail/h/) | Basic HTML | Basic HTML | Basic HTML | Basic HTML |

- **Desktop Mode** refers to the web browser setting, not the link labeled "Desktop" in the Mobile version of Gmail (which links to [Basic HTML Desktop](https://mail.google.com/mail/h/)).
- **Mobile Mode** refers to using **Device Mode** in **Chrome DevTools** to simulate a mobile device. [Chrome for Developers > Simulate mobile devices with Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/)
- **Older Version** (Mobile) can be accessed in from a mobile browser without switching to desktop mode using a link to **Older Version** located at the bottom of the hamburger menu
  [image: Shows the hamburger menu in Mobile Gmail.]
  <sub>[image: Older Version link located at bottom of hamburger menu.]</sub>